# How to make a Windows batch file exit when a file exists in the file structure?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I want to make something like this...

:LoopBegin

if ???? goto End

**some other work goes here***

gotoLoopBegin

:End

The "????" part should be a check that a file exists with the name "exit.txt" for example. If such a file exists in the current folder, I want the batch file to just exit. Is there  a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if exist filename goto End
```

See `if /?` from a command prompt for more details of what is possible. Also notice `goto :EOF` will always goto the end, without needing an explicit label.